# Testing using Selenium

Tags: selenium, c#, selenium-ide

I am a software architect

we use selenium tests with nunit and c#
i am trying to run jmeter load testing using firefox jmeter recorder (for blazemeter)

i was sure selenium has its own cross platform language that you write to but looking at the tests my teams wrote i see it all 100% c# and typed c#

how can i take some of their tests and put them in the jmeter? does anyone know of a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium WebDriver uses [JSONWire](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) **protocol** which is cross-platform. It provides different client libraries i.e. for C#, Java, Python, Ruby, JavaScript.

Once you have tests developed in C# - the easiest option to convert them into JMeter test is record and replay.

You can just record running Selenium tests with [JMeter's Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Follow instructions from [JMeter Proxy Step by Step guide](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) to get recorder up and running. By default it launches proxy on port 8080
2. Configure Selenium tests to use JMeter proxy. C# and Firefox example:

   ```
   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   string jmeterProxy = "localhost:8080";
   OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
   proxy.HttpProxy=jmeterProxy;
   proxy.SslProxy=jmeterProxy;
   profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy);
   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
   ```
3. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to check whether your test is doing what it should be doing
4. Perform parametrization if required (like different usernames for different virtual users) it is usually being done via [CSV Data Set config](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config)
5. [Add virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
6. Run the load test

Comment: I will definitely check this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not locked to Blazemeter and JMeter, you can accomplish similar with Microsoft's own [load testing tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn250793.aspx) (but there is a cost associated)

I found a [tutorial](http://fluentbytes.com/testing-your-web-application-with-selenium-and-mtm-part-1/) on how to integrate the two, hopefully it will help as a starting point.

Comment: maybe we should reconsider this yet again. our main reason for using blazemeter was the selenium tests. not taht we now they are in compatible, maybe we should reconsider

Comment: "not taht we now" => "now that we know"

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware the answer is that its not possible.  This mainly comes down to JMeter depending on JUnit.

Blazemeter themselves [don't offer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) support for it

Comment: thanks @ECiuleo, this is what i found too. I hope someone will make a better observation or offer another more cross platform solution :(